# DB2 query to show subtotals

Tags: db2

Actual query used:

```
SELECT X.TNO,Y.KID,X.TBALANCE FROM    
(SELECT A.TNO,SUM(A.TBAL) TBALANCE,B.CNO FROM TABLE1 A,TABLE2 B    
WHERE A.TNO=B.TNO AND B.CPRIM='Y' AND A.TCODE='M'    
GROUP BY A.TNO,B.CNO) X, TABLE3 Y     
WHERE X.CNO=Y.CNO;
```

Actual Result:

```
TABLE3.KID   TABLE2.TNO   TABLE1.SUM(TBAL)
------------------------------------------  
R23          34           30   
R23          35           40  
R55          38           10   
R55          39           50
```

I have 3 TABLES as below

TABLE1:

```
TNO  TBAL  TCODE 
-----------------   
34      30    M  
35      40    M  
36      50    N  
38      10    M  
39      50    M
```

TABLE2:

```
TNO  CNO   CPRIM  
----------------
34     A3    Y  
34     B3    N  
34     C1    N  
35     D1    Y  
35     D2    N  
38     E2    Y  
38     E4    N  
39     F3    Y  
39     F5    N
```

TABLE3:

```
CNO   KID  
----------  
A3     R23  
35     R23  
E2     R55  
F3     R55
```

Need the result from above 3 tables where TABLE1.TCODE='M' AND TABLE2.CPRIM='Y':

```
TABLE3.KID   TABLE2.TNO   TABLE1.SUM(TBAL)
------------------------------------------  
R23          34           70   
R23          35           70  
R55          38           60  
R55          39           60
```

Please help me achieve the above result

Comment: Hi Charles,                                                                                                I tried the below : SELECT TABLE3.KID,SUM(TABLE1.TNO),TABLE1.TBAL FROM TABLE1,TABL2,TABLE3 WHERE TABLE1.TNO=TABLE2.TNO AND TABLE1.TCODE='M' AND TABLE2.CPRIM='Y' AND TABLE2.CNO=TABLE3.CNO GROUP BY TABLE3.KID,TABLE1.TNO

Comment: You should edit your question and include what you've tried.  As the results your seeing...

Comment: Charles, I edited the question and included what i tried. Pl take a look at it now

Comment: Do you have a typo in your table3 data?  The row (35,R23) seems like it should be (D1,R23)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the results you want?  It doesn't make sense to me...

This would be what I'd consider a standard aggregation:

```
SELECT C.KID,B.CNO, SUM(A.TBAL)
FROM TABLE3 C
     JOIN TABLE2 B ON B.CNO = C.CNO
     JOIN TABLE1 A ON A.TNO = B.TNO 
WHERE B.CPRIM='Y' AND A.TCODE='M'
GROUP BY C.KID,B.CNO
```

But to give the results you appear to be asking for...

```
WITH KIDSUM as (SELECT C.KID, SUM(A.TBAL) as SUMBAL      
                  FROM TABLE3 C                          
                       JOIN TABLE2 B ON B.CNO = C.CNO    
                       JOIN TABLE1 A ON A.TNO = B.TNO    
                 WHERE B.CPRIM='Y' AND A.TCODE='M'       
                 GROUP BY C.KID                          
)                                                        
SELECT K.KID,B.TNO, K.SUMBAL                             
FROM TABLE3 C                                            
     JOIN TABLE2 B ON B.CNO = C.CNO                      
     JOIN TABLE1 A ON A.TNO = B.TNO                      
     JOIN KIDSUM K ON K.KID = C.KID                      
WHERE B.CPRIM='Y' AND A.TCODE='M'
```